# Android Finding newly added row in ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am adding items to a custom ArrayAdapter and then trying to find the newly added row to focus it, (change the background color etc.)
Only in I can't figure out the sequence in which events are going.
My code does something like:
MainActivity receives an `addObject()` event. It calls the Model which will create and return newObject:

```
adapter.add(newObject);
```

in the adapter `getView()` the adapter will allocate (create or reuse) a row-Layout and set it's tag:

```
row.setTag(newObject);
```

and then back in MainActivity addObject() eventmethod:

```
adaptersListview.findViewWithTag(newObject);
```

Only when I put messages in `adapter.getView()` and after the `findViewWithTag`, then it seems like the `findViewWithTag` is executed before the `getView` (which sets the tag).
Is this because the Adapter will run it's `getView` on another thread (UiThread) maybe?
So the `findViewWithTag` will never work.
How can I make sure the adapter has done it's `getView`'s before I do `findViewWithTag` ?

Comment: try to call findViewWithTag in a Runnable posted to a Handler or just listView.post()

Comment: Do you can edit the last row style in getView() ? You can know if is the last row with `int position` and `getCount();`

Answer (score 0):

Using pskink's listView.post() worked for me
I now have code like:

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        View rowToFocus = listView.findViewWithTag(newObject);
        ... more code ...
    }
});
```